# Jupyter "TypeError: invalid type comparison"

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter

Alright, just started a new job and i have been tasked with writing a simple notebook in jupyter. I really want to impress my supervisor and have been working on this code for hours and can't get it to work, hopefully somebody here can help me.

Here is the code I have been working on:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jk2588\Documents\EDA\EDA Practice\top1000_dataset.csv', converters={'GENDER': lambda x: int(x == 'Male')}, usecols = ['MEMBER_ID', 'GENDER', 'Age', 'Dement'])
df_gp_1 = df[['MEMBER_ID', 'Dement']].groupby('MEMBER_ID').agg(np.mean).reset_index()
df_gp_2 = df[['MEMBER_ID', 'GENDER', 'Age']].groupby('MEMBER_ID').agg(max).reset_index()
df_gp = pd.merge(df_gp_1, df_gp_2, on = ['MEMBER_ID'])
df.head()
```

Output: `MEMBER_ID   Age Dement  GENDER
0   000000002 01    36  NaN 0
1   000000002 01    36  NaN 0
2   000000002 01    36  NaN 0
3   000000002 01    36  NaN 0
4   000000002 01    36  NaN 0`

```
df['Dement'] = df['Dement'].fillna(0)
df['Dement'] = df['Dement'].astype('int64')

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 999 entries, 0 to 998
Data columns (total 4 columns):
MEMBER_ID    999 non-null object
Age          999 non-null int64
Dement       999 non-null int64
GENDER       999 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 31.3+ KB

freq = ((df_gp.Age.value_counts(normalize = True).reset_index().sort_values(by = 'index').Age)*100).tolist()
number_gp = 7
def ax_settings(ax, var_name, x_min, x_max):
    ax.set_xlim(x_min,x_max)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_edgecolor('#444444')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
    ax.text(0.02, 0.05, var_name, fontsize=17, fontweight="bold", transform = ax.transAxes) 
    return None
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=number_gp, 
                   ncols=2, 
                   figure=fig, 
                   width_ratios= [3, 1],
                   height_ratios= [1]*number_gp,
                   wspace=0.2, hspace=0.05
                  )
ax = [None]*(number_gp + 1)
features = ['0-17', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-50', '51-55', '55+']  
for i in range(number_gp):
    ax[i] = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, 0])
    ax_settings(ax[i], 'Age: ' + str(features[i]), -1000, 20000)    
    sns.kdeplot(data=df_gp[(df_gp.GENDER == 'M') & (df_gp.Age == features[i])].Dement, ax=ax[i], shade=True, color="blue",  bw=300, legend=False)
    sns.kdeplot(data=df_gp[(df_gp.GENDER == 'F') & (df_gp.Age == features[i])].Dement, ax=ax[i], shade=True, color="red",  bw=300, legend=False)
    if i < (number_gp - 1): ax[i].set_xticks([])
ax[0].legend(['Male', 'Female'], facecolor='w')
ax[number_gp] = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 1])
ax[number_gp].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax[number_gp].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax[number_gp].barh(features, freq, color='#004c99', height=0.4)
ax[number_gp].set_xlim(0,100)
ax[number_gp].invert_yaxis()
ax[number_gp].text(1.09, -0.04, '(%)', fontsize=10, transform = ax[number_gp].transAxes)   
ax[number_gp].tick_params(axis='y', labelsize = 14)
plt.show()
```

I am then met with:

```
    C:\Users\jk2588\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1167: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
    result = method(y)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last
<ipython-input-38-8665030edb1c> in <module>()
 24     ax[i] = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, 0])
 25     ax_settings(ax[i], 'Age: ' + str(features[i]), -1000, 20000)
---> 26     sns.kdeplot(data=df_gp[(df_gp.GENDER == 'M') & (df_gp.Age == features[i])].Dement, ax=ax[i], shade=True, color="blue",  bw=300, legend=False)
27     sns.kdeplot(data=df_gp[(df_gp.GENDER == 'F') & (df_gp.Age == features[i])].Dement, ax=ax[i], shade=True, color="red",  bw=300, legend=False)
28     if i < (number_gp - 1): ax[i].set_xticks([])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
1281 
1282             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1283                 res = na_op(values, other)
1284             if is_scalar(res):
1285                 raise TypeError('Could not compare {typ} type with Series'

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
1167                     result = method(y)
1168                 if result is NotImplemented:
-> 1169                     raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
1170             else:
1171                 result = op(x, y)

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Please help, i have been faced with an absurd amount of errors this week

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how the data looks like. Maybe the `'age'` column is a number and you are comparing it to the strings in `features`?

Comment: Just updated with the output from df.head() and df.info(). I know 'Dement' has some NaN down the column, but that's why i was trying to convert 'Dement' to zeros with .fillna() and then changed it to 'int64' with .astype(). but i still see the invalid comparrison TypeError.

please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Well, `age` seems to be a number, and `features` only contains strings. Such doesn't work. You need something more sophisticated to test the ages and the ranges. Or maybe make an extra column for each individual to store the 'feature'?